-1066598274 on SSIS because of Excel installation?
i have one SSIS job which stops working after some months and i narrowed it down to an Excel popup problem. So whenever i start the Excel 2016 on this server i receive a popup telling me Excel need to reconfigure things. The Server has no connection to the internet but receives windows updates.
The SSIS package is working fine when i am logged in and debugging it from within visual studio. It is working fine unattended and scheduled too as long as excel is starting clean.
The reason it breaks is just the popup and reconfiguring thing. Reinstalling the accessdatabaseengine, accessdatabaseengine64 and excel is the solution to get rid of the popup and make my ssis job working again.
C:\Windows\syswow64\cscript.exe //nologo //B "F:\INTERFACE\xxx.vbs" "F:INTERFACE\xxx.xlsx" "delete_details" "F:\INTERFACE\xxx.xlsm".

Is there a better way in 2024 than to use Excel macros to clean parts of an existing xlsx file in a SSIS job?

Using SSIS to run a Macro in Excel sounds like an XY Problem to me, if I am honest.
